# A and B have 10 dollars each. They bet 1 dollar each time. A wins the final game iff B has no money left.

Tags: probability, statistics

1. For each bet, A has prob = 0.5 to win the 1 dollar from B. and prob = 0.5 to lose 1 dollar to B. How to calculate the probability that A wins the final game?
2. How about for the initial state A has 20 dollars and B has 10 dollars , what's probability that A wins the final game?
3. How about A and B still have 10 dollars each, and A has prob = 0.6 to win each bet, what's probability that A wins the final game?

Thanks!

Comment: How much money do they start with in the first situation?

Comment: 10. @eepperly16 posts the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry $A$ wins with probability $0.5$ for scenario (1). For (2), consider the probability that $A$ wins *given* that, at some point in time, $A$ has $k$ dollars and $B$ has $30 - k$ dollars. Define $p_k$ by

$$
p_k = P(A \text{ wins } | \: A\text{ has } k \text{ and } B \text{ has } 30-k).
$$

Conditioning on whether $A$ wins, we get

$$
p_k = 0.5 p_{k+1} + 0.5 p_{k-1}.
$$

Intuitively, if $A$ wins, $A$ will have $k+1$ dollars and $B$ will have $30 - (k+1)$ dollars and if $A$ loses, $A$ will have $k-1$ dollars and $B$ will have $30 - (k-1)$ dollars. We also have

$$
p_0 = 0, \: p_{30} = 1.
$$

Since once $A$ has $30$ dollars he wins and when $A$ has $0$ dollars they lose. This problem of solving for $p_k$ then becomes a problem of solving a homogeneous linear recurrence relation. The details for how to solve such a system can be found [here](http://web.mit.edu/neboat/Public/6.042/randomwalks.pdf). In the end, we obtain the formula

$$
p_k = \frac{k}{30}.
$$

Thus the probability $A$ wins is $p_{20} = 2/3$. For part (3), you have to instead solve

$$
p_k = 0.6 p_{k+1} + 0.4 p_{k-1}, \: p_0 = 0, \: p_{20} = 1.
$$

The details are much messier in this case and can again be found [here](http://web.mit.edu/neboat/Public/6.042/randomwalks.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation makes a lot of sense.